# Nancy 640 X 480 screen resolution

Tags: nancy

I am having requirement of supporting the nancy bases website in 640 X 480.I am very new to Nancy. I want to know that is there any way to provide this kind of support . if yes, How we can archive this using NancyFx.

What my understanding is I require to create two different css. one to load in normal resolution & second is for the specific to  640 X 480 screen resolution.

So, Before loading any css I require to identify using Nancy that under which resolution the website is rendering.

Let me know if my thinking is wrong or there is something else I require to do for this.

Thanks,
Chirag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to Nancy. Like we said on our user group - you should look into CSS @media queries, it will help you serve different CSS for different resolutions.